# Is there a way to style different element based on CSS :hover selector (where hovered element and affectee are not in relationship)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here in the sample [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/egufip/4/edit) `hover`ing over `a` changes the background color of **First para** to red

- As `a` and `#p1` are siblings
- And this technique(*by changing the selector in b/w*) will work if there is any parent child (*immediate or nested*) b/w both elements

  but what I am looking for is:

  Is there a way to change the background color of **Second para** when mouse is hovered over `a`;

---

**Note:** I am aware of the fact that I can do this easily using JavaScript/jQuery but I am looking for **css** way.

---

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to do this without Javascript.

Comment: No, this is impossible (currently, and will remain impossible under the [Fast Selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles) of the Selectors API in CSS 4) as it requires a parent-selector, which doesn't exist in CSS.

Comment: ohh thanks for the info. css3 hasn't been standardized yet and will have to wait for css4... phewww

Comment: Selectors 3 has long been standardized.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS4 will provide this functionality](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/subject-of-selector-with-child-combinator/). Sadly for you, however, it isn't even a finalised spec yet, and is not implemented in any browser. (even when it is implemented in browsers, it will take some time to gain sufficient install base for it to be usable in everyday CSS code).

For now your only realistic option is Javascript. (this kind of thing is, of course, dead easy in jQuery)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I can stop beating my head :)

Comment: No, while it will provide the selector syntax, it won't allow that selector to be used in CSS (at least not in the CSS Selectors level 4, ref: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles).

Comment: Even with the complete profile, it is not possible. Prove me wrong by showing the code.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: `div:matches(! > a:hover) ~ div > #p2` Obviously, this is purely hypothetical and nobody knows for sure if it'll ever actually work, but my point is that the complete profile actually opens selectors up to a *vast* array of possibilities, as a complex selector is really nothing more than an expression of a relationship between elements in a document tree.

Comment: @BoltClock Interesting. I thought the subject indicator `!` was not allowed there. It sure makes sense, but the draft is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATED: Still With Some Really Funky Finagling!

Believe it or not, this code **works in FF, Chrome, IE9 and 10** to do what you want ([see the example](http://jsbin.com/ecozag/26/edit)). Yes, it is a "hack" as Pumbaa80 has noted. But I like to make "working" hacks for things that seem impossible. Yes, because of the "hackishness" it will not work in all situations (perhaps not in your "real" world situation).

**What the Update Achieved**

1. I believe I worked out a minor bug in FF and Chrome that would cause it to sometimes display still when *not* over just the `<a>`.
2. I figured out how to get IE to work by interposing the `body:before` pseudo element at `z-index: -1` between the `#p1` (`z-index: -2`) and the `#out` div parent. To work, the `:before` must have a `background-color` set and then `opacity: 0` (without that, it is as if it doesn't even exist for "blocking" purposes). Realize that **there are at least two *side effects*** (probably a few others) of this blocking: (a) Links in the `#p1` will not be clickable, and (b) as the OP noted in a comment, text in `#p1` will not be selectable.

Here is the revised code basically just for the `#sec` hover effect, but I did add the combined code here for the original `#p1` hover effect to now trigger off `#out:hover`. However, the code makes it that only the `<a>` *inside* `#out` triggers that `#out:hover`:

```css
body:before { /* used to "block" hover of #p1 triggering */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: cyan;
  opacity: 0;
}

#out {
  height: 0; /* no height of its own; helped the FF/Chrome occasional miss-hover bug */
}

#out:hover #p1, /* revised #p1 hover code */
#out:hover + div p { /* hover of #out triggers for #sec */
  background-color: red;
}

#out a { 
  float: left; /* helps cause #out to only trigger on anchor */
}

#p1 {
  float: left; /* clears the anchor */
  width: 100%; /* keeps it normal div width of 100% */
  position: relative; /* needed for z-index */
  z-index: -2;  /* allows #out to only trigger on anchor and not #p1 hover */
}

#sec {
  clear: left; /* clears floats above it so layout remains as it was */
}
```

Obviously, the elements "not in relationship" is the main issue with a pure CSS solution. What I have attempted to achieve here (mainly successfully for the main browsers... who knows about mobile, etc. browsers) is *capitalizing on the parent element relationship* in such a way to make the hover of the `<a>` only (within that first parent element) be the only trigger for the `:hover` on the parent element itself, so that I could use that to do the hover effects for all the `<p>` elements.

Comment: While this provides a hack for the given example, it doesn't solve the problem in general

Comment: @ScottS its detecting `hover` on `#out` div not on the anchor Which makes #p2 to change background-color even when mouse hovers over the `#out` div. and about negative `z-index` Its working same way in my IE10. By the way thanks for thinking other way around :)

Comment: @Bingo: Yes, that was the intention (to detect `hover` on #out` so that I could get _access_ to `#sec`), but size `#out` to the anchor and make the layout unaffected by all that (so `#p2` is supposed to be changing on hover of `#out` in this solution, but in such a way that only when over the anchor). I mentioned in my answer that it is not working in IE (and yes, that included IE10).

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Certainly, that is obvious. The problem in general cannot be solved by CSS alone as others have noted both here and on numerous other similar "parent selector" questions on SO. But certain cases can sometimes be solved through creative thinking and manipulation of CSS. That was my only point in posting what I was able to achieve so far. My favorite part of CSS is trying to get it to do things that seem impossible under the conditions, but in so doing, yes, I usually have to work with specific examples, not always general solutions. Of course, the non-functioning IE is a big issue.

Comment: @Bingo: I did notice an occasional wrong triggering of hover in FF/Chrome with my original answer. I believe I fixed that as well as made it working for IE9+ (maybe IE8 too). As I note in my update, my "hack" may not work in your actual full fledged live case, but the concept worked on this test case.

Comment: Indeed, it can never be stressed enough that a hack is a hack and isn't designed to work across all scenarios in general; in the event that it *does* (c.f. every IE CSS hack ever), it's by a stroke of luck.

Comment: @ScottS Oh yeah you did it. hahaha although we have to agree that hack comes up with side effects as well : like now #p1 text is not selectable as it has been thrown back by  `z-index: -2;`. But still you deserve a +1 or more :)